# пытаюсь написать телеграмм бота и парсер в одном приложении

Tags: python, многопоточность, telegram-bot

У меня есть два python файла: основной файл - это парсер, а второй- телеграмм-бот (я импортирую его как модуль в основной файл). Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь запустить бота в своем основном файле:

```
def bot_launch():
    telegram_bot.TelegramBot()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot_launch()
    print('bot launched')
    some_info = InfoGetter().get_info()
    print(some_info)
```

А в файле с ботом делаю так:

```
 def __init__(self):
        self.__bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Надпись "bot launched" в терминал не выводится, и дальнейший метод не запускается. Могу ли я запустить своего бота, не блокируя основной поток? То есть мне нужно чтобы все дальнейшие действия после  `bot_launch()` были выполнены, и чтобы моя основная программа и мой телеграмм-бот работали параллельно. Пожалуйста, помогите, если можете. Заранее спасибо! =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за комментарий, исправил!=)

Comment: В `bot_launch`, стартуйте его в потоке: `Thread(target=telegram_bot.TelegramBot, daemon=True).start()`

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за комментарий, теперь все работает как нужно! Хорошего дня!=)

Comment: извините, можно пожалуйста еще одно уточнение: если я ```telegram_bot.TelegramBot``` представлю в качестве переменной ```my_bot```, то как же мне вызвать метод(не статический) класса ```TelegramBot```? Как я понял в  ```my_bot``` будет хранится класс, а не объект класса, а чтобы вызвать метод, мне нужен именно экземпляр класса. Спасибо заранее!