# Как сделать бесконечный цикл для отправки запросов текущего курса валют без прерывания программы

Tags: python, telebot, while

Пишу бота ТГ, в котором одна из функций будет отображение текущего курса валют. Парсер реализовал, все работает, но мне нужно, чтобы после кода с парсером был код с автообновлением курса валют - нашел способ реализовать это только через бесконечный ежесекундный цикл while, но по объяснимым причинам программа дальше не переходит и нижерасположенный код не читается.

Как можно обойти данную особенность питона, чтобы цикл выполнялся параллельно с другим текстом.
Заранее всем огромное спасибо.

```
# парсер курса доллара
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
Dollar_Rub = 'https://www.finam.ru/quote/mosbirzha-valyutnyj-rynok/usdrubtom-usd-rub/'
headers = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Safari/605.1.15')
def get_currency():
    full_page = requests.get(Dollar_Rub, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
    convert = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'PriceInformation__price--26G'})
    time.sleep(5)
    return convert[0].text

def update_currency():
    while 1 > 0:
        a = get_currency()
        print(a)

#именно после вышеуказанного кода программа вниз не спускается

value = update_currency()
```

И ниже идет мой код самого ТГ бота где указаны все остальные его параметры

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, советами, как можно реализовать мою задачу?

Comment: 1) это о чем - "программа дальше не переходит и нижерасположенный код не читается" - куда "дальше"? под строку с `value`? 2) "особенность питона, чтобы цикл выполнялся параллельно с другим текстом" - а в других языках нет такой "особенности"?

Comment: @ Сергей Цикл не дает бота запустить

Comment: @СергейШашко, так это "особенность питона". В С (или в BASIC) легко бы запустился, там такие циклы совсем по-другому работают (и да, спасибо за ответ, тоже увидел уже).

Comment: @ipranka, почитайте про `threading`. Я бы его использовал, если воода-вывода немного, хотя в ботах чаще вижу асинхронный режим.

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1419822/218971 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302045/218971

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA для полного комплекта ссылки на многопроцессорность не хватает :)